# Can an entity be weak when it appears to have 2 owners

Tags: entity, primary-key, relational-database, entity-relationship

I'm designing a database for students making applications to companies for an industrial placement year with a company.

http://i908.photobucket.com/albums/ac286/gegenki/ERModel.png

[Please ignore whether the lines are solid or dashed]

To summarise

A 'Student' may make many 'Application's

An 'Application' has many 'Progress' (A record in Progress stores each update in the application process, like date passed the 1st interview, date of the 2nd interview)

An 'Application' is made for one 'Job'

A 'Company' may offer many 'Job's

Status is a weak entity as it only exists for a particular application.
I don't know if application is a strong entity or a weak entity.
A weak entity's primary key must reference the owner key as one of the attributes.

However I currently have the key for Application being made up of
StudentID from the 'Student' entity
and
JobRef from the 'Job' entity.
2 Foreign keys, from 2 different entities.
Can Application be a weak entity?

My current assumption is that application is a strong identity as making it weak would give it two owners which would be ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ER model convention (as far as I understand it) is that an entity is "weak" if any subset of its primary key is also a foreign key. So Application is weak. In relational modelling terms however this distinction is not very significant and has little or no practical consequence. If you find the weak/strong distinction useful then use it, but if not then I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: Thankyou, this is very useful to me. 'An entity is "weak" if any subset of its primary key is also a foreign key.' I looked at all my entities from a practical standpoint and this can clearly be applied to all of those contain foreign keys. I will make it a weak identity because it makes sense practically, although conceptually, the ownership issue still remains.